# I can't run this code, but in sentdex tutorial it's work

Tags: kivy, python-3.7

I'm learn sentdex tutorial about Kivy framework. In this chapter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsnch676Lco&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfwnDTZWw8H3hN_VRQfq8rF&index=4
he finishing chat app and it works, but I try his code and I've got an error.

Server-socket :

```py
import socket
import select

HEADER_LENGTH = 10

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 1234

# Create a socket
# socket.AF_INET - address family, IPv4, some otehr possible are AF_INET6, AF_BLUETOOTH, AF_UNIX
# socket.SOCK_STREAM - TCP, conection-based, socket.SOCK_DGRAM - UDP, connectionless, datagrams, socket.SOCK_RAW - raw IP packets
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# SO_ - socket option
# SOL_ - socket option level
# Sets REUSEADDR (as a socket option) to 1 on socket
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Bind, so server informs operating system that it's going to use given IP and port
# For a server using 0.0.0.0 means to listen on all available interfaces, useful to connect locally to 127.0.0.1 and remotely to LAN interface IP
server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))

# This makes server listen to new connections
server_socket.listen()

# List of sockets for select.select()
sockets_list = [server_socket]

# List of connected clients - socket as a key, user header and name as data
clients = {}

print(f'Listening for connections on {IP}:{PORT}...')

# Handles message receiving


def receive_message(client_socket):

    try:

        # Receive our "header" containing message length, it's size is defined and constant
        message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)

        # If we received no data, client gracefully closed a connection, for example using socket.close() or socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        if not len(message_header):
            return False

        # Convert header to int value
        message_length = int(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())

        # Return an object of message header and message data
        return {'header': message_header, 'data': client_socket.recv(message_length)}

    except:

        # If we are here, client closed connection violently, for example by pressing ctrl+c on his script
        # or just lost his connection
        # socket.close() also invokes socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR) what sends information about closing the socket (shutdown read/write)
        # and that's also a cause when we receive an empty message
        return False

while True:

    # Calls Unix select() system call or Windows select() WinSock call with three parameters:
    #   - rlist - sockets to be monitored for incoming data
    #   - wlist - sockets for data to be send to (checks if for example buffers are not full and socket is ready to send some data)
    #   - xlist - sockets to be monitored for exceptions (we want to monitor all sockets for errors, so we can use rlist)
    # Returns lists:
    #   - reading - sockets we received some data on (that way we don't have to check sockets manually)
    #   - writing - sockets ready for data to be send thru them
    #   - errors  - sockets with some exceptions
    # This is a blocking call, code execution will "wait" here and "get" notified in case any action should be taken
    read_sockets, _, exception_sockets = select.select(sockets_list, [], sockets_list)


    # Iterate over notified sockets
    for notified_socket in read_sockets:

        # If notified socket is a server socket - new connection, accept it
        if notified_socket == server_socket:

            # Accept new connection
            # That gives us new socket - client socket, connected to this given client only, it's unique for that client
            # The other returned object is ip/port set
            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()

            # Client should send his name right away, receive it
            user = receive_message(client_socket)

            # If False - client disconnected before he sent his name
            if user is False:
                continue

            # Add accepted socket to select.select() list
            sockets_list.append(client_socket)

            # Also save username and username header
            clients[client_socket] = user

            print('Accepted new connection from {}:{}, username: {}'.format(*client_address, user['data'].decode('utf-8')))

        # Else existing socket is sending a message
        else:

            # Receive message
            message = receive_message(notified_socket)

            # If False, client disconnected, cleanup
            if message is False:
                print('Closed connection from: {}'.format(clients[notified_socket]['data'].decode('utf-8')))

                # Remove from list for socket.socket()
                sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)

                # Remove from our list of users
                del clients[notified_socket]

                continue

            # Get user by notified socket, so we will know who sent the message
            user = clients[notified_socket]

            print(f'Received message from {user["data"].decode("utf-8")}: {message["data"].decode("utf-8")}')

            # Iterate over connected clients and broadcast message
            for client_socket in clients:

                # But don't sent it to sender
                if client_socket != notified_socket:

                    # Send user and message (both with their headers)
                    # We are reusing here message header sent by sender, and saved username header send by user when he connected
                    client_socket.send(user['header'] + user['data'] + message['header'] + message['data'])

    # It's not really necessary to have this, but will handle some socket exceptions just in case
    for notified_socket in exception_sockets:

        # Remove from list for socket.socket()
        sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)

        # Remove from our list of users
        del clients[notified_socket]
```

server-client:

```py
import socket
import errno
from threading import Thread

HEADER_LENGTH = 10
client_socket = None

# Connects to the server


def connect(ip, port, my_username, error_callback):

    global client_socket

    # Create a socket
    # socket.AF_INET - address family, IPv4, some otehr possible are AF_INET6, AF_BLUETOOTH, AF_UNIX
    # socket.SOCK_STREAM - TCP, conection-based, socket.SOCK_DGRAM - UDP, connectionless, datagrams, socket.SOCK_RAW - raw IP packets
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        # Connect to a given ip and port
        client_socket.connect((ip, port))
    except Exception as e:
        # Connection error
        error_callback('Connection error: {}'.format(str(e)))
        return False

    # Prepare username and header and send them
    # We need to encode username to bytes, then count number of bytes and prepare header of fixed size, that we encode to bytes as well
    username = my_username.encode('utf-8')
    username_header = f"{len(username):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
    client_socket.send(username_header + username)

    return True

# Sends a message to the server
def send(message):
    # Encode message to bytes, prepare header and convert to bytes, like for username above, then send
    message = message.encode('utf-8')
    message_header = f"{len(message):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
    client_socket.send(message_header + message)

# Starts listening function in a thread
# incoming_message_callback - callback to be called when new message arrives
# error_callback - callback to be called on error
def start_listening(incoming_message_callback, error_callback):
    Thread(target=listen, args=(incoming_message_callback, error_callback), daemon=True).start()

# Listens for incoming messages
def listen(incoming_message_callback, error_callback):
    while True:

        try:
            # Now we want to loop over received messages (there might be more than one) and print them
            while True:

                # Receive our "header" containing username length, it's size is defined and constant
                username_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)

                # If we received no data, server gracefully closed a connection, for example using socket.close() or socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                if not len(username_header):
                    error_callback('Connection closed by the server')

                # Convert header to int value
                username_length = int(username_header.decode('utf-8').strip())

                # Receive and decode username
                username = client_socket.recv(username_length).decode('utf-8')

                # Now do the same for message (as we received username, we received whole message, there's no need to check if it has any length)
                message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
                message_length = int(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())
                message = client_socket.recv(message_length).decode('utf-8')

                # Print message
                incoming_message_callback(username, message)

        except Exception as e:
            # Any other exception - something happened, exit
            error_callback('Reading error: {}'.format(str(e)))
```

main app:

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
import socket_client
import os
import sys
kivy.require("1.11.1")


class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_y=None)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

        self.chat_history = ScrollableLabel(size_hint_y=None, markup=True)
        self.scroll_to_point = Label()

        self.layout.add_widget(self.chat_history)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.scroll_to_point)

    def update_chat_history(self, message):
        self.chat_history.text += '\n' + message

        self.layout.height = self.chat_history.texture_size[1] + 15
        self.chat_history.height = self.chat_history.texture_size[1]
        self.chat_history.text_size = (self.chat_history*0.98, None)
        self.scroll_to(self.scroll_to_point)


class ConnectPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        if os.path.isfile("prev_details.txt"):
            with open("prev_details.txt", "r") as f:
                d = f.read().split(",")

                prev_ip = d[0]
                prev_port = d[1]
                prev_username = d[2]
        else:
            prev_ip = ""
            prev_port = ""
            prev_username = ""
        self.add_widget(Label(text="IP: "))
        self.ip = TextInput(text=prev_ip, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.ip)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Port: "))
        self.port = TextInput(text=prev_port, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.port)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Username: "))
        self.username = TextInput(text=prev_username, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        self.join = Button(text="Join")
        self.join.bind(on_press=self.join_button)
        self.add_widget(Label())
        self.add_widget(self.join)

    def join_button(self, instance):
        port = self.port.text
        ip = self.ip.text
        username = self.username.text

        with open("prev_details.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(f"{ip},{port},{username}")

        info = f"Attempting to join {ip} : {port} as {username}"
        chat_app.info_page.update_info(info)
        chat_app.screen_manager.current = "Info"
        Clock.schedule_once(self.connect, 1)

    def connect(self, _):
        port = int(self.port.text)
        ip = self.ip.text
        username = self.username.text

        if not socket_client.connect(ip, port, username, show_error):
            return

        chat_app.create_chat_page()
        chat_app.screen_manager.current = "Chat"


class InfoPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.message = Label(halign="center", valign="middle", font_size=30)
        self.message.bind(width=self.update_text_width)
        self.add_widget(self.message)

    def update_info(self, message):
        self.message.text = message

    def update_text_width(self, *_):
        self.message.text_size = (self.message.width*0.9, None)


class ChatPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.rows = 2
        self.history = ScrollableLabel(height=Window.size[1]*0.9, size_hint_y=None)
        self.add_widget(self.history)

        self.new_message = TextInput(width=Window.size[0]*0.8, size_hint_x=None, multiline=False)
        self.send = Button(text="Send")
        self.send.bind(on_press=self.send_message)

        bottom_line = GridLayout(cols=2)
        bottom_line.add_widget(self.new_message)
        bottom_line.add_widget(self.send)
        self.add_widget(bottom_line)

        Window.bind(on_key_down=self.on_key_down)

        Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_text_input, 1)
        socket_client.start_listening(self.incoming_message, show_error)

    def ok_key_down(self, instance, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode == 40:
            self.send_message(None)

    def send_message(self, _):
        message = self.new_message.text
        self.new_message.text = " "
        if message:
            self.history.update_chat_history(f"[color=dd2020]{chat_app.connect_page.username.text}[/color]> {message}")
            socket_client.send(message)

            Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_text_input, 0.1)
       #self.add_widget(Label(text="Hey at least it worked up to this point"))

    def focus_text_input(self, _):
        self.new_message = True

    def incoming_message(self, username, message):
        self.history.update_chat_history(f"[color=20dd20]{username}[/color] > {message}")


class EpicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.connect_page = ConnectPage()
        screen = Screen(name="Connect")
        screen.add_widget(self.connect_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.info_page = InfoPage()
        screen = Screen(name="Info")
        screen.add_widget(self.info_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager

    def create_chat_page(self):
        self.chat_page = ChatPage()
        screen = Screen(name="Chat")
        screen.add_widget(self.chat_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)


def show_error(message):
    chat_app.info_page.update_info(message)
    chat_app.screen_manager.current = "Info"
    Clock.schedule_once(sys.exit, 10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    chat_app = EpicApp()
    chat_app.run()
```

This is error in terminal. I have no idea, how it's repair

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "epicApp.py", line 185, in <module>
     chat_app.run()
   File "/home/marek/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/home/marek/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/home/marek/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/home/marek/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/home/marek/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 339, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "/home/marek/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 591, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
   File "epicApp.py", line 92, in connect
     chat_app.create_chat_page()
   File "epicApp.py", line 171, in create_chat_page
     self.chat_page = ChatPage()
   File "epicApp.py", line 116, in __init__
     self.history = ScrollableLabel(height=Window.size[1]*0.9, size_hint_y=None)
   File "epicApp.py", line 23, in __init__
     self.chat_history = ScrollableLabel(size_hint_y=None, markup=True)
   File "epicApp.py", line 19, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/marek/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/scrollview.py", line 513, in __init__
     super(ScrollView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/marek/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 350, in __init__
     super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 243, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Comment: i also got that error working on it.

Comment: You are passing a `markup=True` to your `ScrollableLabel` init, which pases it to its base class `ScrollView`, but `ScrollView` does not support `markup`. Also, are you sure you should be creating another  `ScrollableLabel` inside the `__init__()` method of `ScrollableLabel`? Seems like you are setting up an infinite loop. Perhaps you meant to create a simple `Label` there.

Comment: Your code does not match the tutorial code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
import socket_client
import os
import sys
kivy.require("1.10.1")


class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_y=None)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

        self.chat_history = Label()
        self.scroll_to_point = Label()

        self.layout.add_widget(self.chat_history)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.scroll_to_point)

    def update_chat_history(self, message):
        self.chat_history.text += '\n' + message

        self.layout.height = self.chat_history.texture_size[1] + 15
        self.chat_history.height = self.chat_history.texture_size[1]
        self.scroll_to(self.scroll_to_point)


class ConnectPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        if os.path.isfile("prev_details.txt"):
            with open("prev_details.txt", "r") as f:
                d = f.read().split(",")

                prev_ip = d[0]
                prev_port = d[1]
                prev_username = d[2]
        else:
            prev_ip = ""
            prev_port = ""
            prev_username = ""
        self.add_widget(Label(text="IP: "))
        self.ip = TextInput(text=prev_ip, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.ip)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Port: "))
        self.port = TextInput(text=prev_port, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.port)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Username: "))
        self.username = TextInput(text=prev_username, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        self.join = Button(text="Join")
        self.join.bind(on_press=self.join_button)
        self.add_widget(Label())
        self.add_widget(self.join)

    def join_button(self, instance):
        port = self.port.text
        ip = self.ip.text
        username = self.username.text

        with open("prev_details.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(f"{ip},{port},{username}")

        info = f"Attempting to join {ip} : {port} as {username}"
        chat_app.info_page.update_info(info)
        chat_app.screen_manager.current = "Info"
        Clock.schedule_once(self.connect, 1)

    def connect(self, _):
        port = int(self.port.text)
        ip = self.ip.text
        username = self.username.text

        if not socket_client.connect(ip, port, username, show_error):
            return

        chat_app.create_chat_page()
        chat_app.screen_manager.current = "Chat"


class InfoPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.message = Label(halign="center", valign="middle", font_size=30)
        self.message.bind(width=self.update_text_width)
        self.add_widget(self.message)

    def update_info(self, message):
        self.message.text = message

    def update_text_width(self, *_):
        self.message.text_size = (self.message.width*0.9, None)


class ChatPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.rows = 2
        self.history = ScrollableLabel(height=Window.size[1]*0.9, size_hint_y=None)
        self.add_widget(self.history)

        self.new_message = TextInput(width=Window.size[0]*0.8, size_hint_x=None, multiline=False)
        self.send = Button(text="Send")
        self.send.bind(on_press=self.send_message)

        bottom_line = GridLayout(cols=2)
        bottom_line.add_widget(self.new_message)
        bottom_line.add_widget(self.send)
        self.add_widget(bottom_line)


        Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_text_input, 1)
        socket_client.start_listening(self.incoming_message, show_error)

    def ok_key_down(self, instance, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode == 40:
            self.send_message(None)

    def send_message(self, _):
        message = self.new_message.text
        self.new_message.text = " "
        if message:
            self.history.update_chat_history(f"[color=dd2020]{chat_app.connect_page.username.text}[/color]> {message}")
            socket_client.send(message)

            Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_text_input, 0.1)
       #self.add_widget(Label(text="Hey at least it worked up to this point"))

    def focus_text_input(self, _):
        pass

    def incoming_message(self, username, message):
        self.history.update_chat_history(f"[color=20dd20]{username}[/color] > {message}")


class EpicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.connect_page = ConnectPage()
        screen = Screen(name="Connect")
        screen.add_widget(self.connect_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.info_page = InfoPage()
        screen = Screen(name="Info")
        screen.add_widget(self.info_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager

    def create_chat_page(self):
        self.chat_page = ChatPage()
        screen = Screen(name="Chat")
        screen.add_widget(self.chat_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)


def show_error(message):
    chat_app.info_page.update_info(message)
    chat_app.screen_manager.current = "Info"
    Clock.schedule_once(sys.exit, 10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    chat_app = EpicApp()
    chat_app.run()
```

[image]

[image]

so i tell what i changed... 
self.layout.add_widget(self.chat_history)
to
self.chat_history = Label()

---

def update_text_width(self, *_):
self.message.text_size = (self.message.width*0.9, None)
to
DELETED!

---

def focus_text_input(self, _):
self.new_message = True

to

pass! and deleted.

---

and many more things deleted... but it is somewhat working.

Comment: @JainilPatel Please do not ask not to give you downvote since the vote is free and secret. If you don't do something similar when you receive upvote.